# ShareKit twitter profile picture update error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sharekit

when i try to update the twitter profile picture, i get the following error:

"the operation couldn't be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)"

I've only added one line of code to the original source code: (in the share function)

[item setCustomValue:@"anything" forKey:@"profile_update"];

note: everything else is working, tweets and img.ly uploads.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They've recently patched this. Check out this commit item on github:
https://github.com/openresearch/ShareKit/commit/cdbf2528da12abf8e3c8ce1f52a577f3737b5939

Basically you need to add a check in sendImage to switch between POST and GET based on if it's a "profile_update" request.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's related, but this error is often encountered when attempting use an NSMutableURLRequest to send a POST message without first calling [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

Comment: i was already calling [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; and the app would still crash. thank you for your time...